# JScript runtime error in XSLT: Object required

Tags: xslt, runtime-error, jscript

I have the following pieces of JScript code in my XSLT:

```
    var childAttribute1 = ppDemo1[i].firstChild.attributes;
    if(childAttribute1.length != 0)    
    {
        ....
    }

    var childAttribute2 = ppDemo1[i].childNodes.item(0);
    if(childAttribute2.nodeType != 8)
    {
        ....
    }
```

ppDemo1 points to a commented node/text in XML

I am trying to achieve the same thing i.e. not enter the if loop if the current node is a comment (and has no attributes)

My issue: I always get a runtime error 'Object required' at both of the 'if' clauses

Can you please tell me what is wrong in the above pieces of code

Edited:

I am using the MSXML processor

And, I can get it to work if I use:

```
    if(ppDemo1[i].attributes)  
    {  
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. As using JScript and the API exposed depends on the XSLT processor used, you also need to tell us exactly which XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that earlier. I am using MSXML. I have also updated the post

Answer (score 0):

First piece of code:

The `attributes` property returns `null` for comment nodes ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760261(v=vs.85).aspx)). The "Object required" errors occurs because you are trying to access the `length` property on a null value.

Second piece of code:

For a comment node, `childNodes` always returns an empty node list. Trying to access the first item of an empty node list returns `null`, so you get the same error trying to access the `length` property.

As you discovered, simply testing the return value of `attributes` works, since `null` evaluates to false. If you really do need to check the length of the attributes node list, though, you could do this:

```
if (childAttribute1 && childAttribute1.length != 0) { ... }
```